# React Navigation 5: How can I put route along with other options

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass navigation params inside my navigation.js:

```
import { CATEGORIES, MEALS } from '../data/dummy-data';

     <MealsNav.Screen
                    name="MealDetail"
                    component={MealDetailScreen}
                    options={({ route }) => {
                        const mealId = route.params.mealId;
                        const selectedMeal = MEAL.find(meal => meal.id === mealId);
                        
                        return {
                            title: selectedMeal.title
                        },
    
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Favorite'
                                    iconName='ios-menu'
                                    onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
```

This one doesn't work and I am not seeing the headerRight() being highlighted.

This part works though:

```
 <MealsNav.Screen
            name="CategoryMeals"
            component={CategoryMealsScreen}
            options={({ route }) => {
                const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                return {
                    title: selectedCategory.title,
                };

            }}
        />
```

I just need the route + the other options to sit together.

The error says: `error: Error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (92:31)`

And the headerRight function did not executed since the icon did not shows up.

```
 headerRight: () => (
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Code will not be executed after return  statement. And what's that you're using comma after it? You're supposed it be property? There're many things I cannot understand why?

Comment: No it did work here's the error: `Error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (92:31)`

Comment: And the headerRight function did not executed since the icon did not shows up.

Comment: You probably want `return {title: ..., headerRight:...}`

Comment: oh, hurrah....! You may delete  your post, it's not useful for future visitor.

Answer (score 0):

standart solution

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Info"
              color="#000"
            />
          ),
          })
          }
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Be carefully after return function called
because nothing works after return called